# Creation of a fact table, is that the ETL process?

Tags: excel, tableau-api, data-warehouse

I have created a small data warehouse with the help of Tableau software. First I entered my information in Excel and created my fact table in Excel and then imported into Tableau where I created my queries.

I would like to know if the creation of a Fact table is the ETL process? (I know what ETL means,I just want to know where it happened in my project).

Comment: Sounds more like plain "dataloading" unless there was any "transformation" of your data during the process.  ETL typically refers to pulling data from an existing system/store and reformatting/restructuring it for a different purpose/system.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you do `Extract`, `Transform` and `Load` - but mostly manually. Your Extract procedure is done manually, while gathering the information you need to create your excel sheet. The transformation is then again a manual step, you create the excel sheet based on the data you collected from wherever. And at last, you load the finished excel sheet into your BI system `Tableau`.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau is a data analytics package that helps you look at already gathered data and query it for business intelligence.  It is separate from an ETL tool.

The extract-transform-load process is where data from a system (database, customer relationship system, whatever) is extracted from the data source, it is then transformed/converted so it can be loaded into a data warehouse.  For example, Excel spreadsheets converted to CSV, or changing how dates are formatted in Oracle DB data.  Once the data is in a format that the warehouse can process, it is loaded into the data warehouse.

Tableau can be used to query and analyze the data in a data warehouse to help discover trends or problems in a business.  In and of itself, it is not an ETL tool.

Answer (score -2):

1. Fact table creation is not part of ETL concept. Its related to Data modulation.
2. There is no ETL happening in your process.